# Humanoid Rig force knee of my character to rotate, but it shouldn't be

Tags: unity, animation, skeletal-animation, rigging

Demonstration of the problem - [video](https://youtu.be/NeNNCZ4VJTo)

My export settings

[image]

My Unity import settings

[image]

Rig Settings

[image]

Animation Settings

[image]

Comment: What are you animation import/compression settings?

Comment: @DMGregory I updated my question with new info about export info.

Comment: Thanks, but I asked for the *import* settings.

Comment: @DMGregory I updated my question with Unity FBX import info